# Mobile Java Applet?

Tags: java, mobile, applet

Is there any mobile platform that allows me to run Java Applets? In absence of browser integration, at least Java SE capabilities. I've heard of a mobile device capable of running Windows XP - that would probably include support for Java SE and applets; does any one have any hands-on experience with such a device? How well does it perform in terms of Java programs execution?

Comment: If you are looking to use Java to develop a mobile application, you may be interested in developing for the Android platform. It isn't an applet, but it does use the Java programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the old school java applets which can be embeded in HTML pages there is IMHO no mobile platform which support this. Applets are written in Java SE, however most platforms I know of have a Java ME runtime.

I don't know how this correlates to the new Java FX as there is a mobile profile coming along with it. Can somebody else comment on this issue?

Comment: Java FX runs off of a JRE, You need a JRE before you can run an Applet or JavaFX. Once you have one on your platform how you want to deliver the application Applet, JNLP/Webstart, Java FX doesnt matter really so long as you have developed it for that JRE. 

Meaning if the mobile device has Java ME Runtime, then you can deploy an Applet or Java FX App so long as you build it with that runtime.

Comment: Forgot you can also use the built in mobile emulator for NetBeans to test your App out.

Comment: @Knife - applets and java webstart are not available on J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

Given that java applets are traditionally quite simple, yet depend upon the entire JSE stack, including AWT, trying to run an applet on this is not a good choice for mobile java. Unless of coure "mobile" includes tablet pcs. as you say, these run XP and could run the full J2SE stack. This would run your applet unmodified. You can expect a lot of tablets to be released this year to compete with the iPad. E.g. Just one pulled at random. http://www.tabletpc2.com/TEGA_Tablet_to_be_Officially_Launched.html

But if tablets are not what you had in mind, then read on.

If you are starting new development, you will be better served with J2ME, which is far more common on mobile devices. J2ME doesn't support AWT or Swing, but has it's on UI classes. JavaFX is also a candidate, as the mobile profile doesn't depend upon the JSE stack.

If you already have an applet that you want to run on a mobile platform, you may find that porting it is not that difficult. CLDC with MIDP 2.0 has a 2D api (e.g. look at google maps mobile, or opera mobile) and can handle most of the typical tasks appets are used for.

Comment: I want to be able to run already compiled applets on a mobile platform, not modify their code.

Comment: ok, then I think you're looking at a tablet pc as a solution.

Comment: Depending on the app and the target price bracket for the phone, you might be better off targeting android if you're developing a new app. I'm not sure where J2ME makes sense outside of symbian phones.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly a lot of [mobile internet devices](http://www.dynamism.com/71/category.shtml) and [netbooks](http://www.amazon.com/s/url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=netbooks&x=0&y=0) which would allow you to run a java applet.  Essentially anything that would run Windows 7/Vista/XP, and many that run linux would allow you to run applets.

As far as how it will perform it probably depend on the applet.  I'm sure simple applets will perform just fine.  Some applets which do a lot more won't be so fast.  Netbooks/MID are as powerful as notebook from maybe 6 or 7 years ago.  Java ran just fine on computers from that era, so they should be fine on an MID.